# How to extract attachments from a ZFO?

Tags: extract

Does anyone know how to extract the attachments from a .zfo file (602 form filler). Its a format based on openXML.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

In my experience .zfo messages are just signed XML files (CMS/PKCS #7 standard). All you need to do is to remove the encrypted envelope, which gives you a XML file that you can easily read. In case of Czech ISDS all attachments are listed in a `<p:dmFiles>` element.

XML example:

```
...
<p:dmFiles xmlns:p="http://isds.czechpoint.cz/v20">
  <p:dmFile dmMimeType="doc" ... >
    <p:dmEncodedContent> ... </p:dmEncodedContent>
  </p:dmFile>
  <p:dmFile dmMimeType="pdf" ...>
    <p:dmEncodedContent> ... </p:dmEncodedContent>
  </p:dmFile>
</p:dmFiles>
```

You can reach the content elements using C# like this:

```
var message = new  System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.SignedCms();
message.Decode(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("message.zfo"));

var doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(message.ContentInfo.Content))
{
    doc.Load(ms);
    var list = d.DocumentElement.GetElementsByTagName("p:dmEncodedContent");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about this format, but since you said "`OpenXML`", you probably just need to open it and decode base64 data;

Answer (score 1):

According my research it's zipped .fo file.
If you rename .zfo to .zip, you'll be able to open it with usual archiver and you find there .fo file which is in xml format you can view with any text editor.

Answer (score 1):

on linux

ZFO -> XML

```
openssl smime -inform DER -in file.zfo -verify -noverify -out file.zfo.xml
```

in XML are in element

```
<p:dmFiles>
```

attachements data (file name, file type, data)

Answer (score 0):

The following (happy-path) bash script should be enough. It uses `openssl`, `xsltproc` and `base64`, all a very commonly available tools in most Linux distros. See [my GitHub](https://github.com/tlwhitec/czechia-digital-services/blob/master/extract-zfo.sh) for a more robust version.

```sh
$ cat extract-zfo.sh
#!/bin/bash
# verify and strip signature
xml="$(openssl smime -inform DER -verify -noverify -in "$1")"
# list all attachments
stylesheet='
  <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:for-each select="'"//*[local-name()='dmFile']"'">
        <xsl:value-of select="@dmFileDescr"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>'
files="$(xsltproc <(printf '%s' "$stylesheet") - <<<"$xml")"
# dump all attachments
while read -r file; do
  stylesheet='
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
      <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
      <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="'"//*[local-name()='dmFile' and @dmFileDescr='$file']/*[local-name()='dmEncodedContent']/text()"'"/>
      </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>'
  xsltproc <(printf '%s' "$stylesheet") - <<<"$xml" | base64 -d > "$file"
done <<<"$files"
```

Usage:

```
$ ./extract-zfo.sh a-file.zfo
```

Kudos to @knedle for the openssl part!