# How to remove zip compression from an XML file?

Tags: c#, compression, zip

I have an XML file format `.zfo` that is compressed using zip algorithm. I need to remove this compression from the file, so that it is in usable XML form. Here is [the file](http://cid-d53719d869fb8243.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/Public/31602.zfo).

How can I remove this compression, or decompress this XML file?

It's not like you might imagine i.e: `.zip` file containing an xml file. Instead the `byte[]` that's written to the file is zip compressed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you upload the file somewhere. so that it can be examined a little more. ie If the information is not sensitive

Comment: http://cid-d53719d869fb8243.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/Public/31602.zfo

Comment: if u are on linux, read this answer

http://stackoverflow.com/a/25282337/2524117

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That file isn't zip compressed at all.  It appears to be some xml that's embedded in a certificate, issued by the Czech Post Office.  The actual message looks to be encoded in some kind of base64 variant.

Call your post office.

Answer (score 1):

Check out DotNetZip (http://www.codeplex.com/DotNetZip)--it probably does what you need (e.g., DeflateStream).

A zip file contains meta-data (file and directory structure) as well as the actually compressed data. It sounds like your file only has the compressed data. DotNetZip should be able to handle both.

Comment: Unfortunately it expects a traditional zip file structure. My file is not a zip, but the contents are compressed using zip algorithm

Comment: ZIP isn't aan algorithm. ZIP is a file format. The compression algorithm used within most zip files is DEFLATE. That's what the DeflateStream handles - a raw bytestream that has been deflated.